# How to include header files to c++ dll file

Tags: c++

I want to include iostream inside a c++ dll file but am getting "fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory" error.

How can I include header files in a dll file?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362364/ideal-way-to-include-headers-from-a-dll

Comment: @Mohit Then flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such a thing like "include header files in a dll file".
What you can do is:
include header files in a source code file (i.e. *.cpp),
then compile it to create a shared library (DLL file on Windows platform).